# Cannot read X509 certificates from certificate store in a web application

Tags: .net, security, cryptography

I cannot see any X509 certificates when running this code from a web application:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            string thumbprint = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateThumbprint"];

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thumbprint))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Please specify the X509 certificate thumbprint in the web configuration file.");
            }

            Certificate = store.Certificates
                .Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true)
                .OfType<X509Certificate2>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            store.Close();

            if (Certificate == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The specified X509 certificate has not been installed on this server.");
            }
```

When debugging, I can see that `store.Certificates` is empty. However, it runs perfectly well in a Console app.. this is odd because I have seen examples online using the above code in a web application.

It would be helpful if the code would throw some kind of permission exception or something from the web app to tell me why I can't read them, but it doesn't. So, is there some permissions I need to set somewhere or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the certificate in the TrustedPeople store instead and it works fine:

`var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);`

Answer (score 0):

To get past the permission issue, export the certificate to a .pfx file (password protected). To export with the mmc: add snap-in -> certificates, then export (and set the password on) the cert to a convenient location. Then

```
var certF = new X509Certificate2(
                    @"D:\somedir\withaccess\exported.pfx", "password!");
```

Why move a certificate from the `StoreName.Root` which is for Trusted Root Certification Authorities?

If permissions allow, stores not in the `StoreName enums` can be accessed by name, e.g. for "WebHosting":

```
var store = new X509Store( "WebHosting", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```